# I am trying to create a formula with multiple parameters that may or may not have a value entered

Tags: crystal-reports

I am trying to create a formula with multiple parameters that may or may not have a value entered.

The database field and corresponding parameters are:
`{DataTableTicket.Master_Account_Code}={?MastNo})`
`{DataTableTicket.Description}={?RTCode}`
`{DataTableTicket.Problem_Code}={?ProbCode}` 
`{DataTableTicket.Resolution_Code}={?ResCode}`
`{DataTableTicket.Customer_Number}={?CustNo}` 
`{DataTableTicket.Master_Account_Code}={?MastNo})`

I am trying to write an IF THEN statement that takes into consideration the various combinations, since you can enter in a ?MastNo value but not populate the rest of the parameters.

I think the basic formula would be something like this (if parameter is blank then all records else parameter).  What I am struggling with is how to get that basic formula created since there are so many combinations.

Comment: I'm assuming you know how to determine if a parameter has a value entered or not and just want some help with the logic

Comment: Which version of Crystal Reports?  Are they optional parameters?

Answer (score 0):

For each parameter that "may or may not have a value", set it to a default value.

If the value for the parameter is entered then set the parameter to the entered value.

Comment: So, if {?MastNo} is null then 'ALL' else {DataTableTicket.Master_Account_Code}={?MastNo}.  

Do I need to join them together? Would it look like this:
If IsNull({?Tech}) and IsNull({?RTCode}) and IsNull({?ProbCode}) and IsNull({?ResCode}) and IsNull({?CustNo}) and IsNull({?MastNo}) 
then 'ALL' else ({DataTableAppointments.Technician} = {?Tech}) and 
({DataTableTicket.Description}={?RTCode}) and ({DataTableTicket.Problem_Code}={?ProbCode}) and ({DataTableTicket.Resolution_Code}={?ResCode}) and 
({DataTableTicket.Customer_Number}={?CustNo}) and 
({DataTableTicket.Master_Account_Code}={?MastNo})

Answer (score 0):

I usually do something like:

```
// Assumes that 0 represents all values; single value; numeric
( 0={?Parameter} OR {Table.Field}={?Parameter} )

// Assumes that 0 represents all values; multiple values; numeric
( 0 IN {?Parameter} OR {Table.Field} IN {?Parameter} )
```

In your situation:

```
( 0={?MastNo} OR DataTableTicket.Master_Account_Code}={?MastNo} ) AND
( 0={?RTCode} OR {DataTableTicket.Description}={?RTCode} )
...
```